# Selenium post request python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I need to login to a website, however, it has a hidden recaptcha field that I cannot use send_keys (element not interactable). Is there any possibility of making a POST request with selenium or selenium requests?

Answer (score 3):

With Python you should be able to use something like this:

```
webdriver = Firefox()
response = webdriver.request('POST', 'url', data={"x": "y"})
```

Alternatively, execute the POST request via JavaScript:

```
jsrequest = '''var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '{{URL}}', false);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send(param1=value&param2=value2');
return xhr.response;'''

result = driver.execute_script(jsrequest)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Josh, but apparently, when making the request this way, the browser window follows the following strange behavior:

1 - Opens in the url data :,

2 - Opens a tab on the home page of the website

3 - Close the tab and return to the date :,

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to make the request and use the session after the request for selenium already access the page with the session started and the user logged in?

Comment: You can construct the `POST` request in JavaScript as an `XMLHttpRequest`, then execute that script via Selenium.

See edit to the answer.